# Intersection in sqlite3 in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to extract data that corresponds to a stock that is present in both of my data sets (given in a code below).

This is my data:

```
#(stock,price,recommendation)
my_data_1 = [('a',1,'BUY'),('b',2,'SELL'),('c',3,'HOLD'),('d',6,'BUY')]

#(stock,price,volume)
my_data_2 = [('a',1,5),('d',6,6),('e',2,7)]
```

Here are my questions:

Question 1:

I am trying to extract price, recommendation, and volume that correspond to asset 'a'. Ideally I would like to get a tuple like this:

```
(u'a',1,u'BUY',5)
```

Question 2:

What if I wanted to get intersection for all the stocks (not just 'a' as in Question 1), in this case it is stock 'a', and stock 'd', then my desired output becomes:

```
(u'a',1,u'BUY',5)
(u'd',6,u'BUY',6)
```

How should I do this?

Here is my try (Question 1):

```
import sqlite3

my_data_1 = [('a',1,'BUY'),('b',2,'SELL'),('c',3,'HOLD'),('d',6,'BUY')]

my_data_2 = [('a',1,5),('d',6,6),('e',2,7)]

 #I am using :memory: because I want to experiment
 #with the database a lot

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') 

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_1
          (stock TEXT, price REAL, recommendation TEXT )''' )

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_2
          (stock TEXT, price REAL, volume REAL )''' )



for ele in my_data_1:
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_1 VALUES(?,?,?)''',ele)

for ele in my_data_2:
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_2 VALUES(?,?,?)''',ele)    

conn.commit()

# The problem is with the following line:

c.execute( 'select* from my_table_1 where stock = ? INTERSECT select* from my_table_2 where stock = ?',('a','a')  )

for entry in c:
    print entry
```

I get no error, but also no output, so something is clearly off.

I also tried this line:

```
c.execute( 'select* from my_table_1 where stock = ? INTERSECT select volume from my_table_2 where stock = ?',('a','a')
```

but it does not work, I get this error:

```
    c.execute( 'select* from my_table_1 where stock = ? INTERSECT select volume from my_table_2 where stock = ?',('a','a')  )
sqlite3.OperationalError: SELECTs to the left and right of INTERSECT do not have the same number of result columns
```

I understand why I would have different number of resulting columns, but don't quite get why that triggers an error.

How should I do this?

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like those two questions are really the same question.

**Why your query doesn't work:** Let's reformat the query.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table_1 WHERE stock=?
INTERSECT
SELECT volume FROM my_table_2 WHERE stock=?
```

There are two queries in the intersection,

1. `SELECT * FROM my_table_1 WHERE stock=?`
2. `SELECT volume FROM my_table_2 WHERE stock=?`

The meaning of "intersect" is "give me the rows that are in both queries".  That doesn't make any sense if the queries have a different number of columns, since it's impossible for any row to appear in both queries.

Note that `SELECT volume FROM my_table_2` isn't a very useful query, since it doesn't tell you which stock the volume belongs to.  The query will give you something like `{100, 15, 93, 42}`.

**What you're actually trying to do:** You want a join.

```
SELECT my_table_1.stock, my_table_2.price, recommendation, volume
    FROM my_table_1
    INNER JOIN my_table_2 ON  my_table_1.stock=my_table_2.stock
    WHERE stock=?
```

Think of join as "glue the rows from one table onto the rows from another table, giving data from both tables in a single row."

It's bizarre that the price appears in both tables; when you write the query with the join you have to decide whether you want `my_table_1.price` or `my_table_2.price`, or whether you want to join on `my_table_1.price=my_table_2.price`.  You may want to consider redesigning your schema so this doesn't happen, it may make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer; it does exactly what I was looking for. Also, thank you for the explanation, I needed that :).

Answer (score 2):

You are suffering from a misunderstanding about how to correlate different tables.

In order to do this the easiest way is to JOIN them with a suitable condition, resulting in results which automatically include the data from both the joined tables. In the example below I select all columns, but you can of course select only those you want by naming them in the FROM clause. You can also select only those rows you want with (a) further condition(s) in a WHERE clause. After you execute you code, try the following:

```
>>> c.execute("select * from my_table_1 t1 JOIN my_table_2 t2 ON t1.stock=t2.stock")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1004608f0>
```

This tells SQLite to take rows from table 1 and join them with rows in table 2 meeting the conditions in the ON clause (*i.e.* they have to have the same value for their STOCK attribute). Because you chose such long table names, and because I am a crappy typist, I used table alises in the FROM clause to allow me to use shortened names in the rest of the query.

```
>>> c.fetchall()
```

then gives you  the result

```
[(u'a', 1.0, u'BUY', u'a', 1.0, 5.0), (u'd', 6.0, u'BUY', u'd', 6.0, 6.0)]
```

which would seem to answer both 1) and 2). For only a particular value of STOCK just add

```
WHERE t1.STOCK = 'a'  -- or other required value, naturally
```

to the query string. You can see the names of the columns returned by querying the cursor's description attribute:

```
>>> [d[0] for d in c.description]
['stock', 'price', 'recommendation', 'stock', 'price', 'volume']
```

The INTERSECT operation is used to take the outputs from two separate SELECT queries and return only those elements that occur in both. I don't think that's going to be helpful here. The reason you got the error is because the queries have to be "UNION compatible", which is to say they need the same number and type of columns in the intersected queries.